# split strings and convert to data frame

Tags: r

I have a 65k element character vector, of the format. The length of each element is different, but ranges from 3 to 8 based on commas.:

```
b[1]= "aaaa, bbbb, cccc"
...
b[1000]="aaaa, bbbb, cccc, dddd, eeee, ffff"
...
b[3000]="aaaa, bbbb, cccc, dddd, eeee, ffff, gggg"
b[3001]="aaaa, bbbb, cccc"
```

I want to convert to a data frame:

```
row  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
1    aaaa bbbb cccc
1000 aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff
3000 aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg
```

I tried:

```
 data.frame( do.call( rbind, strsplit( b, ',' ) ) )
```

and got:

> Warning message:
>       In (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :
>         number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)

Any suggestions?

Comment: What happened to the reproducible examples on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `read.csv` after pasting the string together and collapsing with `"\n"`.

```
read.csv(text = paste0(b, collapse = "\n"), header = FALSE)

#    V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7
#1 aaaa  bbbb  cccc                        
#2 aaaa  bbbb  cccc  dddd  eeee  ffff      
#3 aaaa  bbbb  cccc  dddd  eeee  ffff  gggg
```

If you want to read empty strings as `NA` specify them in `na.strings`

```
read.csv(text = paste0(b, collapse = "\n"), header = FALSE, na.strings = "")
```

---

Another option is `stri_list2matrix` from `stringi`

```
data.frame(stringi::stri_list2matrix(strsplit(b, ","), byrow = TRUE))

#   X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7
#1 aaaa  bbbb  cccc  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
#2 aaaa  bbbb  cccc  dddd  eeee  ffff  <NA>
#3 aaaa  bbbb  cccc  dddd  eeee  ffff  gggg
```

**data**

```
b <- c("aaaa, bbbb, cccc", "aaaa, bbbb, cccc, dddd, eeee, ffff", 
       "aaaa, bbbb, cccc, dddd, eeee, ffff, gggg")
```

Comment: unfortunately for me, when I work on a subset of my data, this works, but when I use the entire set, everything is forced into 3 columns

Comment: @alex Not sure what would have happened there since I am not able to reproduce the issue however, I added another option with `stri_list2matrix`

Comment: thanks for the second option, it worked. Not sure why the first option did not work.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `fread` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
fread(paste(b, collapse="\n", sep=""), fill = TRUE)
#   V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7
#1: aaaa bbbb cccc                    
#2: aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff     
#3: aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg
```

#### data

```
b <- c("aaaa, bbbb, cccc", "aaaa, bbbb, cccc, dddd, eeee, ffff", 
   "aaaa, bbbb, cccc, dddd, eeee, ffff, gggg")
```